# Can I have multiple views per viewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

Here is a related question I found, but it does not answer my question in detail.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209993/cocoa-touch-can-i-have-multiple-views-per-view-controller-or-specify-bounds-of][1]

I have a UIView class, `BallView`, which is set to be the default view of the ballViewController. Now, this view has a ball bouncing around according to the accelerometer. I am calling a private function `draw` every time the accelerometer sends updates.

However, my main question is: I would like to have multiple such balls bouncing around.

Do I have to recreate the view for every class ? But then the File's Owner's IBOutlet `view` will also have to be connected. And an IBOutlet can point to just one address.

Any other way round this ?

Here is how I'm instantiating the `Ball View` class in the ballViewController:

```
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:
 ^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error){
     [(BallView *)self.view setAcceleration:accelerometerData.acceleration];
     [(BallView *)self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(draw) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
 }];
```

Thus, it means, my question is a bit different from those multi-view tab-bar solutions. Because in those cases only 1 view is shown at a time. I want 4-5 views overlaid on top of each other.

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, your view controller can only have a single `UIView` in its `view` property. That view though can certainly be used to contain other subviews.

What I would do is have a plain old `UIView` as your controller's `view`, and have your `BallViews` be subviews of that view. Your controller can still control those views, they ust can't all be in its `view` property.

**EDIT:** If you're using nib files/Interface Builder, adding a `BallView` as a subview of your controller's view is pretty easy - just drag a `UIView` object onto the view, and in the identity inspector you can change the identity of the view to your `BallView` class.

If you're not using IB, you can also do the same programatically:

```
// BallViewController.h
@interface BallViewController
{
    BallView* ballView;
}

@end

// BallViewController.m
@implementation BallViewController

- (void) loadView
{
    ...

    CGRect frame1 = ...
    CGRect frame2 = ...

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];

    ballView = [[BallView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2] retain];
    [self.view addSubview:ballView];

    ...
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Mac, So.. when I want the viewController's view, I do `self.view`. What do I have to do to get the subviews ?

Comment: @Hrishikesh: I've added some example code for you. Hopefully that answers some of your questions. Sorry, I don't have XCode/Interface Builder at hand, so my description may not be 100% accurate (I'm working just from memory).